# How to send parameter to a click binding knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to send a value to the function called when the user click a button.

Here is the view model,

```
define(["knockout", "text!./index.html", "../../components/users/users"], function (ko, indexTemplate, userModel) {
function indexViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    var id = 1;
    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server/getUsers.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {"data":id},
        success: function (result) {
            var row = JSON.parse(result)
            for(var i=0;i<row.length;i++){
                self.users.push(new userModel.userModel(row[i]["name"],row[i]["time"],row[i]["id"]));
            }
        }
    });
    self.removeUser = function (user) {
       alert(user);
    };
    return self;
    }
return { viewModel: indexViewModel, template: indexTemplate };
});
```

Here is the html page,

```
<!-- ko foreach: users -->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="" style="height:180px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: removeUser.bind($data,$data.id)">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I want to get the $data.id when the user click the button. I tried removeUser.bind($data,$data.id) but there is an error.
removeUser is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the removeUser is not defined because it is in the parent model, so try `$parent.removeUser`. 
If all you want is to remove the selected item from array. Then just try as follows

```
<!-- ko foreach: users -->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="" style="height:180px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $parent.removeUser">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

and in the model

```
define(["knockout", "text!./index.html", "../../components/users/users"], function (ko, indexTemplate, userModel) {
function indexViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    var id = 1;
    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server/getUsers.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {"data":id},
        success: function (result) {
            var row = JSON.parse(result)
            for(var i=0;i<row.length;i++){
                self.users.push(new userModel.userModel(row[i]["name"],row[i]["time"],row[i]["id"]));
            }
        }
    });
    self.removeUser = function () {
  self.users.remove(this);
    };
    return self;
    }
return { viewModel: indexViewModel, template: indexTemplate };
});
```

Comment: Can you explain more about $root, $parent, $data?

Comment: @JohnArellano There is a good amount of documentation in the following link http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html